# Flutter await for another method complete

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check if new update is available for my application or not. if update is available redirect user to `UpdateScreen` and if update is not available get the user info and redirect to `HomeScreen`

```
_check() async {

  await _checkForUpdate();
  
  await _getUserData(token);

}
```

```
  _checkForUpdate() async {
     print('check for update');
      var url = Uri.parse(Endpoints.mainData);
      var response = await http.get(url);

      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

      var data = jsonResponse['data'];


      int lastVersionCode = data['lastVersionCode'];

      if(lastVersionCode > Data.versionCode){
        redirectToScreen(context, UpdateScreen());
      }
  }
```

```
_getUserData(String token) async {
    print('get user data');
    var url = Uri.parse(Endpoints.accountInfo + '/?token=' + token);
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var data = jsonResponse['data'];

    //setup user data in my app
    redirectToScreen(context, HomeScreen());
```

When I run my application two methods( _checkForUpdate, _getUserData) get fired and in output I the get following message that i printed:

```
check for update
get user data
```

and i see Update screen for 1 second and then user is redirect to `HomeScreen`.

i want to skip running the other codes after `_checkForUpdate` redirect user to `UpdateScreen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return a bool whether there is an update available and use it to skip other methods:

```
_check() async {
  bool needsUpdate = await _checkForUpdate();
  if (!needsUpdate)
      await _getUserData(token);
}


Future<bool> _checkForUpdate() async {
     print('check for update');
      var url = Uri.parse(Endpoints.mainData);
      var response = await http.get(url);

      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      var data = jsonResponse['data'];

      int lastVersionCode = data['lastVersionCode'];

      if (lastVersionCode > Data.versionCode) {
        redirectToScreen(context, UpdateScreen());
        return true;
     }
     return false;
  }
```